# How to prevent an <img> tag from loading its image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which take a string with html information (containing also reference to images).

When I create a DOM element the content for the image is being downloaded by the browser. I would like to know if it is possible to stop this Beauvoir and temporary prevent loading.

I am targeting web-kit and presto browsers.

```
  relativeToAbosluteImgUrls: function(html, absoluteUrl) {
        var tempDom = document.createElement('div');
        debugger
        tempDom.innerHTML = html;
        var imgs = tempDom.getElementsByTagName('img'), i = imgs.length;
        while (i--) {
            var srcRel = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
            imgs[i].setAttribute('src', absoluteUrl + srcRel);
        }
        return tempDom.innerHTML;
    },
```

Comment: As soon as you set the `src` attribute, loading will start. So a solution would be to not set the `src` attribute until when you want the loading to start.

Comment: It *will* download once it has a value for `src`.  The only way you can stop it downloading is to stop it before it's sent to the client (server-side script).  How is the page created - is it html/php/asp etc.?  Don't accept client-side suggestions as you can't stop it at the browser - it's too late.

Comment: Set a custom `data-src` attribute that holds the source, and when you want the image to load, set the actual `src` attr

Comment: when calling this method I pass html. html contain code like <img src="http://www.mysite.com/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> for my understanding the loading start at tempDom.innerHTML = html; so when I do tempDom.getElementsByTagName... the image are already downloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should reverse the logic, don't load the images by default and at the moment the image is needed, update it's src attribute to tell browser to start loading.

Or even better way would be to use some jquery lazy image loading plugin like this one:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added a comment to my question

Answer (score 10):

Store the `src` path into an HTML5 data-* attribute such as `data-src`. Without `src` being set, the browser will not download any images. When you are ready to download the image, simply get the URL from the `data-src` attribute and set it as the `src` attribute

```
$(function() {
    // Only modify the images that have 'data-src' attribute
    $('img[data-src]').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).data('src');
        // modify src however you need to, maybe make
        // a function called 'getAbsoluteUrl'
        $(this).prop('src', src);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The approach taken by popular image library, [Slimmage](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage), is to wrap your `img` tags in `noscript` tags:

```
<noscript class="img">
  <img src="my-image.jpeg" />
</noscript>
```

Web scrapers and people with JS turned off will see the image as if the `noscript` wasn't there but other browsers will completely ignore the `noscript` *and* `img` tags.

You can then use JavaScript to do whatever you want with it, for example (using jQuery):

```
$('noscript.img').replaceWith(function(){
    return $(this.innerText).removeAttr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent images from being show, you could use this.

```
    $(window).loaded( function() { 
$("img").removeAttr("src");
 });
```

It might be tricky and give unexpected results, but it does it.

Comment: This may remove the images from being displayed on the page, but Idk if it blocks the browser from downloading them in the background once the download has started in the first place. And since this is inside a `$(document).ready()`, *all* of the `<img>` tags present in the original page markup will have started downloading.

Comment: Didn't think about that, although that might be, it's already 1 'step' closer to the answer, if you know what I mean.